# I like Stripes but I'm using sl4j/logback for logging, what are my options?

Tags: java, stripes

Since stripes comes with commong-logging. What are my options in using stripes in a web applications without commons logging. How can I replace it with sl4j logging library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to redirect Commons Logging log to SLF4J, you need to remove Commons Logging from the classpath and add JCL-over-SLF4J bridge.

Here you can find a solution of similar problem for Spring: [Logging Dependencies in Spring](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/04/logging-dependencies-in-spring/).

Comment: This page gives an explanation of how to proceed : http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html

Comment: Thanks. Do you think that this is a flaw in the Stripes framework to be dependent on commons-logging?

Comment: It really does not matter what kind of logging a Java library uses, slf4j can handle them all fine.